# USB camera detected but not working

Tags: drivers, usb, 22.04, webcam, camera

I am using ubuntu 22.04 and I connected a usb camera, the system detects that there is a camera and its detected on cheese.

when I use lsusb I get:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1903:8328 Generic HD camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

even when I use guvcview it starts recording, which means my camera is 100% detected, but when I use cheese I just get a black screen.

When I run guvcview it starts recording but the video contains nothing, I have tried almost everything and I can't get anywhere.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Based on the reputable data [at LinuxHardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:1903-8328), that camera does not work with any Linux distribution at this time 

Comment: If it was supported you would have had to have installed a driver.

Answer (score 0):

Well I thought the interaction between virtualbox's usb option and the operating system was strange, so I just installed ubuntu on my laptop as a second OS, plugged the webcam and it worked just fine.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you asked. Great the camera works but your question does not have a valid answer.

Comment: Better than just leaving this unsolved, if it worked for me then maybe it could work for someone else using virtualbox and having the same issue, right?